# Java-SWIG and vtkSmartPointer

Tags: java, c++, swig, vtk

I have a class `Foo` which expects two Parameters in the ctor:

```
typedef vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> t_renderer;
typedef vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> t_rwindow;
typedef vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> t_interactor;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(renderer> ren, interactor inter);
    // ...
}

// Usage:
t_renderer   ren   = t_renderer::New();
t_rwindow    rwin  = t_rwindow::New();
t_interactor inter = t_interactor::New();

Foo f(ren, inter);
f.method1();
// ...
```

With SWIG I would like to have the same in Java:

```
vtkRenderer ren = new vtkRenderer();
// ...
Foo f = new Foo(ren, inter);
f.method1();
// ...
```

The problem is, that SWIG generates two files:

- SWIGTYPE_p_vtkSmartPointerT_vtkRenderer_t.java
- SWIGTYPE_p_vtkSmartPointerT_vtkRenderWindowInteractor_t.java

Also the java ctor of Foo looks like that:

```
public Animator(SWIGTYPE_p_vtkSmartPointerT_vtkRenderer_t renderer, SWIGTYPE_p_vtkSmartPointerT_vtkRenderWindowInteractor_t inter) {
   ...
}
```

So my question is: How can i avoid this in SWIG? My interface file is:

```
%module(directors="1", allprotected="1") swiganimator

%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_shared_ptr.i>

%{
    #include <memory>
    #include <string>
    #include "Foo.hpp"
%}

%shared_ptr(OtherType)

%include "Foo.hpp"
```

I hope you unterstand the problem described here.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that SWIG needs to be told about template instantiations; otherwise, it won't generate code for them.

```
%template(spRenderer)   vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>;
%template(spWindow)     vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>;
%template(spInteractor> vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>;
```